# sudo: main: unable to allocate memory (Inside of Linux Container)

Tags: wine, sudo, ram, container

I am trying to build a 32 bit version of Wine in a Linux container. When I start the container, attach, and login, and enter the command `sudo apt-get update` I get the error `sudo: main: unable to allocate memory.` I tried setting the `overcommit_memory` to 1, but it still does not work. Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you following the WineHQ wiki to build Biarch 32 / 64 bit wine?

Try:

```
apt-get update
```

without the `sudo`

I was rejected trying to sign into the container and had to Attach to it using `sudo`.

My prompt was:

```
sudo@my32bitbox
```

It was not:

```
username@my32bitbox
```

After a couple of hours reading about `main: unable to allocate memory`
and getting nowhere I realized some other diagnostic commands ran fine without `sudo` so I tried the update and the other 2 commands that follow it and they worked fine without `sudo` as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and yes I was trying to build Biarch wine. I found the same thing. Apparently, the Linux container already had root access.